# Swift having image in background not changing with subview

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift4, addsubview

I have a view that displays 1 picture at a time and that picture is supposed to be the background image. I also have other elements on top of that image that are supposed to change on touch  . The view that I have is called **VideoView** and I have elements on top . All of this works my problem is that when I use **insertSubview** all the elements on top change (like they are supposed to) but the image stays the same (VideoView) and it is supposed to change . If I replace the **InsertSubView** with **addSubview** then the image changes correctly on click but my top elements do not show . I know that what I'm supposed to use is **insertSubview** and on touch I can see the image URL changing but the screen stays with the first default image .

*I think I know what might be going on . On every tap I am adding a new InsertSubview and the new image might be behind the old image . I verified by uploading a video . I first had an image and when I tapped to go to the next screen the image stayed however the video sound came on .*

```
class BookViewC: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var VideoView: UIView!

    var imageView: UIImageView?



override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
  // This is how I change images, touchCount number is linked with unique image depending on the number passed in .

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self.VideoView)


          if location.x <  self.VideoView.layer.frame.size.width / 2 {
            if touchCount == 0 || touchCount < 0 {
                touchCount = 0
            } else {
                touchCount = touchCount - 1

            }
           reloadTable(Offset: touchCount)
        }
        else {
            touchCount = touchCount + 1
            reloadTable(Offset: touchCount)

        }
    }
}

func ShowImage(s_image: String) {
    let imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: s_image)!
    let request:NSURLRequest =  NSURLRequest(url: imgURL as URL)
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    bookviewImage.imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: s_image))
    bookviewImage.imageView?.frame = VideoView.bounds
    bookviewImage.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill


    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest,    completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

            if data != nil {

                self.bookviewImage.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.VideoView.insertSubview(self.bookviewImage.imageView!, at: 0)
               // self.VideoView.addSubview(self.bookviewImage.imageView!)

            } else {
                self.bookviewImage.imageView!.image = nil
            }

        })
    });
    task.resume()
}





    func reloadTable(Offset: Int) {

    // send http request

        session.dataTask(with:request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {

            } else {
                do {

       let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]

   if let Streams = parsedData["Results"] as? [AnyObject]?
       {

     if self.streamsModel.Locations.count >= 0 {
                         // Get Results

                        }


        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          for Stream in Streams! {



if let s_image = Stream["stream_image"] as? String {                                    
self.ShowImage(s_image: s_image)

 }
     }
       }
```

[image]

This background Image on InsertSubview does not change on click however when I add AddSubview the background image changes so I know there is something wrong in my code since the InsertSubview background image is not updating

[![ .][2]][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are changing pictures and might have to see the code to provide a better explanation. In the meantime, you should understand the difference between `insertSubview` and `addSubview`.

**addSubview:**

`addSubview` adds a view at the end of the list. In the hierarchical structure, this would be the bottom most item. On screen, however, it would be the top most item covering everything underneath it.
The hierarchy would look like

- View

  - Video View

    - Profile Image
    - Time
    - Full Name
    - Post
    - Button
    - **imageView**

**insertSubview:**

`insertSubview` inserts a view at a given position in the list. Your code is inserting at position 0. In the hierarchical structure, this would be the top most item. On screen, however, it would be the bottom most item covered by everything on top of it.
The hierarchy would look like

- View

  - Video View

    - **imageView**
    - Profile Image
    - Time
    - Full Name
    - Post
    - Button

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks that definitely helps out, that's why when I put InsertSubview at 1 it hid the Profile Image . I am new to swift .

Comment: @user1591668 Glad to be of help. Please accept the answer if the issue is resolved. If there's any confusion left, do let me know

Comment: I am definitely closer to solving my issue . I created a more detailed post . Essentially my InsertSubview image is supposed to be changing on click and it isn't happening even though everything else is changing on click .

Comment: That worked I simply created the image in ViewDidLoad and then called InsertSubview instead of creating a new image every time .